# .Net Coe App in Linux fails with - ProjectFactory did not find Project

Tags: linux, api, .net-core, console, publish

### **Following is my server environment**

- Server : VPS
- Host   : AWS EC2
- OS     : CentOS Linux 8.3.2011
- Plesk  : Plesk Obsidian 18.0.34
- .Net Version : .Net Core 3.1.11 (Installed manually from linux CLI)

### **What I am look for**

I have created a .Net core test application and tried to run the app using following and everything works fine. App runs fine with "Hello World!", All Good.

```
dotnet new console
dotnet run
```

But when I tried to publish and run the app,

```
dotnet publish -c Release 
dotnet -d contest.dll
```

It gives following error, I have made sure path and file names all are proper.

```
Telemetry is: Disabled
projectfactory: MSBUILD_EXE_PATH = /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.111/MSBuild.dll
projectfactory: MSBuild project path = 
projecttoolscommandresolver: ProjectFactory did not find Project.
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.CommandUnknownException: Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-contest.dll does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
   at Microsoft.DotNet.CommandFactory.CommandFactoryUsingResolver.Create(ICommandResolverPolicy commandResolverPolicy, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath, String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I have tried API, Console and other templates. Error remains same for all.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dotnet contest.dll` first. Please note the absence of option `-d` in the command.

Even then it does not run most likely it is a permission issue. Does the user have executable permissions?
You can try giving permissions using `chmod ### directory/where/dotnet/publish` is done. Try giving 777 permissions and check.

You can also try clearing Nuget cache files at `/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/` using command `rm /tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/*` if the some other user has used `chmod` command. Sometimes nuget lock files do create issues if multiple users have access to `lock` directory.

Comment: Many Thanks @Nischal. It was definitely the permission issue with the folder. I have plesk installed and executables were inside /var/www/vhosts. Giving the permission and cleaning NuGets solved the issue.

Comment: In my case `dotnet app.dll` works. But `dotnet -d app.dll` gets the same error on Linux ? Any idea why ?